# "php bin/console server:run" immediately followed by "composer require symfony/mailer" whenever it is run

Tags: php, command-line, terminal, symfony-4.4

I'm working on a Symfony project and would like to know why whenever I run the following command in terminal `php bin/console server:run` it would be immediately followed by this one `composer require symfony/mailer`. This is a screenshot of terminal:

[image]

Moreover, this is what I get as an output on http://127.0.0.1:8000/:

[image]

You can notice that the command text "composer require symfony/mailer" shows at the top of the page.

So, how can I handle that? Any idea?

P.S:

- Symfony version: 4.4
- PHP version: 8.0.12
- IDE: PhpStorm

Comment: In PHPStorm, go to Edit -> Find -> Find in Files, and search for `composer require symfony/mailer`. It sounds like it's been added to a file somewhere

Comment: Bunch of thanks! I've found it in the bundle.php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is finally resolved! Making a search for `composer require symfony/mailer`  (by going to "Edit"->"Find"->"Find in Files" in PhpStorm), I found it added somehow in the bundles.php file.